# Getting values separately instead of getting jointly inside foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here i have two tables please have a look

[image]

[image]

the first table `department` have department details and the second table `locations` have location details.in order to get the corresponding values of  location_id other that the numbers i had given my code like this

```
<?php
$no = 1;
foreach ($detail as $s) {
    foreach ($locations as $location) {
        if (!empty($s->location_id)) {
            $loc = explode(',', $s->location_id);
            $loca = array();

            foreach ($loc as $lo) {
                if ($lo == $location->id) {
                    $loca[] = $location->location_name;
                    var_dump($loca);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $loca; ?></td>   

    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

By using this code am getting my result like this
[image]

i want my result to be like this
[image]

Comment: first your question is not clear what do you want to achieve, second, $lo == $location->id never match, first one is id(int) itself, second one comma separated values

Comment: second one comma separated value is being exploded

Comment: what you got in $detail variable show it

Comment: i had edited my question and i think now it will be more clear to you  and my `$detail` contains the value of `department` table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the fact that you should use the proper DB functions for that - this should work.

```
foreach ($detail as $s)
{
    $arrData = [];
    foreach ($locations as $location)
    {
        if (!empty($s->location_id))
        {
            if (in_array($location->id, explode(',',$s->location_id)))
            {
                $arrData[] = $location->location_name;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($arrData))    $s->Location = implode(', ', $arrData);
}
print_r($detail);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is that you need to create a third `joins` table. Your location_id isn't very database friendly because it has to process each element within the field. Imagine if you need to add another element to the location_id field? It becomes difficult.

You need to create a table something like:

`DepartmentID/LocationID`

Then you can use a better query to get the data you need.